# @input is not working for Api response value- angular

Tags: angular6, angular5, angular7

I am using two components parent component and child component and I want to pass the value from parent to child and I used @input method

**------------------------------When I hardcoded the value----------------------------------**

**PARENT COMPONENT**

**ts file**

```
ngOnit(){
    this.name='JOB';
}
```

**html file**

```
<app-parent [name]='name'></app-parent>
```

**CHILD COMPONENT**

```
@input name: any

ngOninit(){
   console.log(this.name)
}
```

**------------------------------ When I passed value from Api----------------------------**

**PARENT COMPONENT**

**ts file**

```
ngOnit(){
    getMethod();
}

getMethod(){
    this.apiService.getAll(data)
      .subscribe(data => {
        if (data.success) {
            this.name=data.data.name
        }
      });
  }
}
```

**html file**

```
<app-parent [name]='name'></app-parent>
```

**CHILD COMPONENT**

```
@input name: any

ngOninit(){
   console.log(name)
}
```

Here when console, the value is *undefined*

Why its not working .Can anybody help me ??

Comment: It's not guaranteed to already be set by `ngOnInit`, because the value is being set asynchronously; use `ngOnChanges` to watch for updates to the `@Input`.

Answer (score 0):

```
....

@Input name: any; // change the @Input decorator. You used a lowercase "i"

....

ngOninit(){
   console.log(this.name) // access the class property using "this"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using input with I capital.
try with this snippet.

```
   @Input() set name(name: string) {
    if (name) {
        this._name= name;
    }
}
```

_name: string

Now console this._name on ngoninit, even then if it will not work, you have to use next life cycle hook (afterviewinit).

This will make name a property and set it every time it change.

Thanks